# where do I place CustomLog directive in apache

Tags: php, docker, apache

I am using a php:7.2-apache docker. I need to disable healthcheck url from logging into access log.

Based on this [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/setenvif_apache2) they mention about modifying Customlog directive. I am not about the file where I need to make the change for Customlog directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CustomLog** parameter in apache conf file. Please look the following code. If you using centos locate that **/etc/httpd/conf.d/** inside.

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  ServerName global
  LogLevel error
  ErrorLog /var/www/html/logs/global-error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/logs/global-access.log combined
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/global
</VirtualHost>
```